# Появляется outline при наведении.

Tags: css, hover, outline

Появилась странная проблема -- в хэдере при наведении на объекты появляется белый outline. Я нигде не писал outline, но и если написать *{ outline: none; }, то всё равно не помогает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Где появляется, у каких объектов, в каком браузере ? И код тоже бы неплохо приложить.

Comment: в reset.css обычно так пишу :focus { outline: 0; } чтобы снять везде выделение, но это при фокусе, а не при наведении

Comment: После проверки оказалось, что проблема в том, что я использую background-blend-mode. Использую последний google chrome.